# sizeWithFont method is deprecated. boundingRectWithSize returns an unexpected value

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, ios7, uilabel

In iOS7, `sizeWithFont` is deprecated, so I am using `boundingRectWithSize`(which returns a CGRect value). My code:

```
 UIFont *fontText = [UIFont fontWithName:[AppHandlers zHandler].fontName size:16];
                    // you can use your font.

 CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(310, 9999);

 CGRect textRect = [myString boundingRectWithSize:maximumLabelSize   
                             options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                             attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:fontText}
                             context:nil];

 expectedLabelSize = CGSizeMake(textRect.size.width, textRect.size.height);
```

In `textRect`, I'm getting a size greater than my `maximumLabelSize`, a different size than when using `sizeWithFont`. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: I am getting this issue with all fonts not only system font or Helvetica.

Comment: do you have any idea how to do that?

Comment: Concrete example for font name, text and mismatching sizes might be helpful.

Comment: I used to use CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints in iOS6 for calculating height of attributedString which always return correct height.
In iOS7, both CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints and boundingRectWithSize give me a wrong height result.
I bet it is a bug introduced in iOS7 and it seems no solution yet.

Comment: Im also facing same problem its better to use tttattributedlabel

Comment: Im also facing same problem, its better to use TT

Comment: But here great answered by developers,i consider it and working fine

Answer (score 152, accepted):

How about create new label and using `sizeThatFit:(CGSize)size` ??

```
UILabel *gettingSizeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
gettingSizeLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"YOUR FONT's NAME" size:16];
gettingSizeLabel.text = @"YOUR LABEL's TEXT";
gettingSizeLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
gettingSizeLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(310, CGFLOAT_MAX);

CGSize expectSize = [gettingSizeLabel sizeThatFits:maximumLabelSize];
```

Edit: This upper code is not good for ios 7 and above, so please use below:

```
CGRect textRect = [myString boundingRectWithSize:maximumLabelSize   
                         options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin| NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading
                         attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:fontText}
                         context:nil];
```

Comment: this method is not working when i am adding HTML entities like(<OL>,<LI>) in string.

Comment: please check my answer again! I missed numberOfLines property! sorry!

Comment: After hours and hours of searching, experimenting and dead-ends, this is the only solution that works for iOS7 and Xamarin / Monotouch

Comment: Creating label to calculate size for font? That's so wasteful!

Comment: @Ossir, do you have a better idea?

Comment: @Luda if you're using in a uitableview, you can create a label as a private property and reuse it.

Comment: This didn't work for me, it returned the same incorrect value as sizeThatFits:

Answer (score 37):

Maybe you need to provide additional option to the method that is suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15399767/1948606) answer:

```
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(310, CGFLOAT_MAX);
CGRect textRect = [myString boundingRectWithSize:maximumLabelSize   
                                         options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                      attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: fontText}
                                         context:nil];
```

Comment: It looks like the `boundingRectWithSize` is broken. I tested on iOS 7, 7.1.1 and it returns not correct results.

Comment: This did not work for me, however using boundingRectWithSize on an NSAttributedString and adding my font attribute to the string instead did work.

Comment: Guys, don't forget about the Apple statement: __In iOS 7 and later, this method returns fractional sizes (in the size component of the returned CGRect); to use a returned size to size views, you must use raise its value to the nearest higher integer using the ceil function.__

Comment: ceil wasn't enough for me, but found that using ceil and also adding 0.5 did the trick

Answer (score 15):

Here is my working code snippet:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:attributeDict];

NSString *headline  = [dict objectForKey:@"title"];  
UIFont *font        = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];  
CGRect  rect        = [headline boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(300, 1000) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font} context:nil];

CGFloat height      = roundf(rect.size.height +4)
```

I added 4px to the calculated height, because without these 4px, there is one line missing.

I use this code snippet in a tableView and add the "height" to an array of NSNumbers and I get the correct cell height for the default textLabel.

Add 4 more pixel if you want more space under the text in the textLabel.

**** UPDATE ****

I do not agree with the "width bug of 40px", I shout be the 4px of missing height, because 4px is the default height of a space between a letter and the bound of a single line.
You can check it with a UILabel, for a fontsize of 16 you need a UILabel height of 20.

But if your last line has no "g" or whatever in it, the measuring could be miss the 4px of height.

I rechecked it with a little method, I get an accurate height of 20,40 or 60 
for my label and a right width less than 300px.

To support iOS6 and iOS7, you can use my method:

```
- (CGFloat)heightFromString:(NSString*)text withFont:(UIFont*)font constraintToWidth:(CGFloat)width
{
    CGRect rect;

    float iosVersion = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
    if (iosVersion >= 7.0) {
        rect = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(width, 1000) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font} context:nil];
    }
    else {
        CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width, 1000) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    }
    NSLog(@"%@: W: %.f, H: %.f", self, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
    return rect.size.height;
}
```

**** UPGRADE ****

Thanks to your comments, I upgraded my function as followed. Since sizeWithFont is deprecated and you will get a warning in XCode, I added the diagnostic-pragma-code to remove the warning for this particular function-call/block of code.

```
- (CGFloat)heightFromStringWithFont:(UIFont*)font constraintToWidth:(CGFloat)width
{
    CGRect rect;

    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:)]) {
        rect = [self boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(width, 1000) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font} context:nil];
    }
    else {
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
        CGSize size = [self sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width, 1000) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
    }
    return ceil(rect.size.height);
}
```

In addition to the 4px topic: 
depending which font and font-weight you use, the calculation returns different height-values. In my case: HelveticaNeue-Medium with a fontsize of 16.0 returns a line-height of 20.0 for a single line but 39.0 for two lines, 78px for 4 lines --> 1px missing for every line - beginning with line 2 - but you want to have your fontsize + 4px linespace for every line you have to get a height-result. 

Please keep that in mind while coding!

I don´t have a function yet for this "problem" but I will update this post when I´m finished.

Comment: You should probably be using [text respondsToSelector:@selector(boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:)] rather than checking a float value.

Comment: It's better to use ceil function instead of +4pt, look at this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/a/23563152/667483

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you are using boundingRectWithSize: just as a way of getting the size you would get with sizeWithFont (meaning you want directly the CGSize, not the CGRect)?

This looks like what you are looking for :

[Replacement for deprecated sizeWithFont: in iOS 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897896/replacement-for-deprecated-sizewithfont-in-ios-7)

They are using sizeWithAttributes: to get the size, as a replacement for sizeWithFont.

Do you still get the wrong size using something like this :

```
UIFont *fontText = [UIFont fontWithName:[AppHandlers zHandler].fontName size:16];
                    // you can use your font.

expectedLabelSize = [myString sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:fontText}];
```

Comment: but how can i use CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(310, 9999)? I need correct height and width.

Comment: Is there any attributes that tells sizeWithAttributes: to constraint its width/height?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get what your problem is. You want to size the label with the font size, but not more than a maximum height, if I understand correctly. You say that you are able to do that with sizeWithFont, but you want an alternative now that this method is deprecated, correct ? You should be able to plug in sizeWithAttribues: in the same way you were using sizeWithFont: . How were you constraining the label size when you were using sizeWithFont ? Can you post the code that was working for you using sizeWithFont ?

Comment: He was using sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode: and there is no way to pass constrainedToSize value to sizeWithAttributes.

Answer (score 2):

The @SoftDesigner's comment has worked for me

```
CGRect descriptionRect = [description boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(width, 0)
                                                       options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                                    attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]}
                                                       context:nil];
result = ceil(descriptionRect.size.height);
```

Answer (score 1):

for finding size of label run time **sizewithfont** is deprecated for iOS 7.0 instead of that you have to use **-boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:** method

you can use it like below code

```
CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(MAXIMUM_WIDHT, TEMP_HEIGHT);
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, [[self.message body] length]);

NSDictionary *attributes = [YOUR_LABEL.attributedText attributesAtIndex:0 effectiveRange:&range];
CGSize boundingBox = [myString boundingRectWithSize:constraint options:NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading attributes:attributes context:nil].size;
int numberOfLine = ceil((boundingBox.width) / YOUR_LABEL.frame.size.width);
CGSize descSize = CGSizeMake(ceil(boundingBox.width), ceil(self.lblMessageDetail.frame.size.height*numberOfLine));

CGRect frame=YOUR_LABEL.frame;
frame.size.height=descSize.height;
YOUR_LABEL.frame=frame;
```

here you have to give width to maximum length for finding height or width.

try this it is working for me.