# Calculate UITableViewCell height to fit string

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `NSMutableArray`, which could contain several hundreds of different strings. Each string is user defined and could have any length, yet no more than an average paragraph.

I need to find out how many lines each string could take. So, I could calculate the required height for a every `UITableviewCell`.

Comment: Can you use `UITextView` inside `UITableViewCell` ?

Comment: What is an `NSMutable*`????

Comment: i see no reason why not, i change font size, font, text colour, background colour props that i can use on textview also.

Comment: sorry autocorrect decided that NSMutableArray dosnt exist but NSMutable does

Comment: Beside `UITextView` i see this option: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19398674/sizewithfont-method-is-deprecated-boundingrectwithsize-is-returning-wrong-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code to calculate and to set the height for cell:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Define `veryverySmallTitleFont`
    // Define `descLabel`

    NSString *ourText = @"Your string data from array";
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:veryverySmallTitleFont];
    font = [font fontWithSize:veryverySmallTitleFont];

    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(descLabel.frame.size.width, 1000);
    CGSize labelSize = [ourText sizeWithFont:font
                           constrainedToSize:constraintSize
                               lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    return labelSize.height;
}
```

Comment: sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode is now deprecated.

Answer (score -1):

I personally use a convenience method which I then send a message to in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return [self cellHeightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}

- (CGFloat)cellHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellString = <YOUR MODEL OBJECT>;

    NSDictionary *attributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0f] };
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]
                                                   initWithString:cellString
                                                   attributes:attributes];

    CGFloat width = self.tableView.frame.size.width - 32.0f;
    CGRect frame = [attributedString boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(width, MAXFLOAT)
                    options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin context:nil];

    // Add some extra padding to the height
    CGFloat height = frame.size.height + 16.0f;

    return ceil(height);
}
```

And of course, I set the `numberOfLines` property of my `UILabel` to `0` in `UITableViewCell`.