# Change cell height depending on text length

Tags: ios, ios7, uitableview

I have an issue with changing height of cell depending on text length. I'm trying to calculate cell height using this code:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return [self dynamicHeightAtIndexPath:indexPath] + 32;
}

- (CGFloat)dynamicHeightAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(275, 9999);
    UIFont *myFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Light" size:15.0];
    CGSize stringsize = [[[self.userAdsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name"]
                         sizeWithFont:myFont
                         constrainedToSize:maximumSize
                         lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    return stringsize.height;
}
```

And I've got these results (5th cell from the top is broken):

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23077829/calculate-tableview-list-cell-height-to-fit-string/23080315#23080315

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
- (CGFloat)dynamicHeightAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *myText = [[self.userAdsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name"];
    CGRect textSize = [myText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(275.0f, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                       options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading
                       attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Light" size:15.0f]}
                       context:nil];
    return fabs(textSize.size.height);
}
```

Not sure what type does the object for key `@"name"` have, but the above code works for `NSString`. Hence the declaration is for clarity.

Comment: Nope, this doesn't fix it. The same issue is occurring. Thanks though!

Comment: Then check where you set the font for the Cell Label, i suspect you're setting it to something other than [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Light" size:15.0]; or the width possibly isn't 275.0

Comment: The only other place the font is set is on the dynamic prototype cell on the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I just wrap the text height calculate function to a category of `NSString`.

In the `.h` file:

```
@interface NSString (Additions)

- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font;
- (CGSize)sizeWithFontSize:(float)fSize constrainedToSize:(CGSize)cSize;
- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)cSize;

@end
```

In the `.m` file:

```
#import "NSString+Additions.h"

#define kSystemVersion ([[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion].intValue)

@implementation NSString (Additions)

- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font
{
    return [self sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)
            {MAXFLOAT, MAXFLOAT}];
}

- (CGSize)sizeWithFontSize:(float)fSize constrainedToSize:(CGSize)cSize
{
    UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:fSize];
    return [self sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:cSize];
}

- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)cSize
{
    if (kSystemVersion < 7)
    {
        CGSize size = [self sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:cSize
                       lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        return size;
    }
    else
    {
        NSDictionary *stringAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName:font};
        CGRect rect = [self boundingRectWithSize:cSize
                       options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin |
                               NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading
                       attributes:stringAttributes
                       context:nil];

        return rect.size;
    }
}

@end
```

Then, just calculate the string's height in the place you want. such as:

```
CGSize cSize = (CGSize){THE_LABEL_WIDTH_HERE, MAXFLOAT};
NSString *tmpString = @"Hello there. I'm junkor, and you can call me jun.";

// will use the system font
float height = [tmpString sizeWithFontSize:15 constrainedToSize:cSize].height;
```

The height is what you want. Sometimes, when you calculate the size of the text, you can cache the size to the data entity, such as in the `tableView`'s delegate function:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

When you reload data or scroll the `tableView`, it always calculates, makes a cache to the height (or size). Make sure you just calculate once for every text, it's better.

Answer (score -1):

Please, try this:

```
- (CGFloat)dynamicHeightAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(275, 9999);
    UIFont *myFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Light" size:15.0];

    NSString *text = [[self.userAdsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name"];
    CGFloat height = [text sizeWithFont:myFont constrainedToSize:maximumSize].height;

    return height;
}
```

Comment: sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize is deprecated.

Comment: Yet it works. Also, it was deprecated only in iOS 7.0. And I don't see any alternative for it if you need to support iOS 6.0.