# Get number of characters in one line of UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

**I have to do the following calculation:**

I have to count how many `characters` may be put in one line of `UILabel`(with spaces). In my app I have big text and I have to count how many characters of this text may be put in the first line of `UILabel`.

I've found different similar solution, for example how to count number of rows in `UILabel`, etc. But I can't find anything according to my question, could you please help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25193520/determine-the-maximum-number-of-characters-a-uilabel-can-take OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23290960/how-to-count-how-many-characters-can-come-in-a-uilabel-line

Comment: to handle big text for label you can have different solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could approach the problem in a different way. You can decide how many characters you allow in one label.

let limitLength = *whatever length you want to allow*

```
func textField(username: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    guard let text = username.text else { return true }
    let newLength = text.characters.count + string.characters.count - range.length
    return newLength <= limitLength
}
```