# 'sizeWithFont(_:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:)' is unavailable: Use -boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:

Tags: ios, swift, uifont

I have to extend the size of TextView by based on its text but it have show the issue but I unable to fix it so please help me for fix this issue.I post the code what I am tried.

```
var size: CGSize = text.sizeWithFont(UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(13), constrainedToSize: textSize, lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping)
```

Comment: See the (ObjC) solutions and suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19398674/sizewithfont-method-is-deprecated-boundingrectwithsize-returns-an-unexpected-va

Comment: Ok Thanks. But If you give Swift solution means that is very helpful for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I translated the answer from [this ObjC question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19398674/sizewithfont-method-is-deprecated-boundingrectwithsize-returns-an-unexpected-va) into Swift; what may be tripping you up is that you need to cast `String` to `NSString`.

Swift 4

```
let text = "Hello"
let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: UIFont.systemFontSize)
let maxSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)

let size = (text as NSString).boundingRect(with: maxSize,
        options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin, .usesFontLeading],
        attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:font],
        context: nil)
    .size
```

Swift 3

```
let text = "Hello"
let font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(UIFont.systemFontSize())
let maxSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: CGFloat.max)

let size = (text as NSString).boundingRectWithSize(maxSize,
        options: [.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, .UsesFontLeading],
        attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:font],
        context: nil)
    .size
```

Comment: I use This Code Means It shows like "Cannot convert value of type 'UIFont' to expected argument type 'CGSize'".Then I give the Full function here...  let text: NSString = message.text!
        let textSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 260.0,height: 10000.0)
        let size = (text as NSString).boundingRectWithSize(UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(13),
            options: [NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, .UsesFontLeading],
            attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:font],
            context: nil)

Comment: Thanks for you help it properly works now...Very very thanks @Kevin