# CGRect - boundingrectwithsize for long NSString not working

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsstring, cgrect, heightforrowatindexpath

I have this method that returns the height of NSString and returns the height on tableview method : heightForRowAtIndexPath but when the NSString gets longer than maybe 2 paragraphs a small section at the end of the string gets cut off.

```
- (float)heightWithFont:(UIFont *)font width:(float)width {    
CGRect frame = [string boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(width, 9999.f)
                                  options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                               attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName: font}
                                  context:nil];
return frame.size.height; }
```

Comment: Are you sure that the width is correct? 1 pixel could matter.

Comment: The width is based on the screen size. UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.width - 16.f which is the baseHeight.

Comment: Why isn't it based on the size of the table view?  And where did the 16 come from?

Comment: 16 is hardcoded to give it extra spacing, Im not sure why its not based on the tableview (working on code that was written by someone else). But I tried to base it on the tableview and the result is the same.

Comment: Base it on the table view an then figure out what the 16 needs to be changed to.

Comment: Changed the 16 to 40 and the string is no longer cut out but some strings had more/extra spaces at the end.

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084760/nsstring-boundingrectwithsize-slightly-underestimating-the-correct-height-why/23563152#23563152